# Forge Viewer - Custom background image

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

My understanding is that we can add [custom skyboxes to the viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093441/how-to-set-up-skybox-in-autodesk-forge/45135420#45135420). As of now I am also aware the feature that changes background color and gradient. However, is it possible to add a custom background image? This would've been really helpful in our scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, if your models are translated from Inventor, and you had set custom background up before uploading, then you can see the user-defined background shows up in the Forge Viewer. In contrast, your models are from another software, I have to say sorry there is no APIs or existing feature for that without adding the skybox.

However, I have logged a similar case in our internal case system a few months ago to make our engineering team allocate time to take a look, its' id is `DERI-4307`. You can track updates of this request by sending this id to `forge.help@autodesk.com` in the further.

**P.S. As I know, viewer requires some extra textures for changing the viewer background with custom images. Unfortunately, there is no way to generate this on none Inventor models currently. You can refer some information about the `DERI-4307` here :
[How to add custom environment map for background in autodesk forge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156353/how-to-add-custom-environment-map-for-background-in-autodesk-forge)**

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I did give it a try using a custom background set in 3DS Max, but unfortunately this didn't work. Could I add an request to add 3DS Max to the list with Inventor of programs that supports custom background?