# Inventor (ipt) custom background image

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

It came to my knowledge that custom background images can't be uploaded with the model to the Forge viewer (or added from any code) - but - by using Inventor there is a workaround. Or should be if I am correct?

I've added my custom background image to my model in Inventor using [these steps](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor-products/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Adding-background-image-to-modeling-windows.html), however the changes doesn't reflect in the viewer (still displaying the environments)

Would anyone kindly share the correct steps with me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45135420/4838205

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves, Thanks. However the skybox is not directly what we are looking for in this case, as we are aiming to implement a specific background (instead of the color/gradient that is currently possible through viewer.setBackgroundColor(255,0,0,255,255,255).  I am refering to the answer given in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164719/forge-viewer-custom-background-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the [mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164719/forge-viewer-custom-background-image) and checked with a few colleagues working on it: this still under research and we don't have the proper steps to make it work. It is logged as a feature request.